# Issues implementing Bluetooth LE in xcode application

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I'm currently working on a small project, where the purpose of it is to create an application using Xcode and that application is supposed to scan and connect to a bluetooth module (The bluetooth module in question is nrf51822), and once that connection between the application and BLE device is lost, then the application sends a push notification to the user saying that the connection to the device is lost. I have already designed an interface and tried some codes from youtube and online guides, downloaded and imported Corebluetooth framework, but nothing is working. Looking at it as a whole it's a simple project that can be done in an hour even, but writing the code for xcode application is difficult for me, especially considering I just started learning about xcode recently. Can anyone please guide me on how to approach this? or a simple xcode code that will be able to scan and connect to the device.

The device CBUUID is 6E400003-B5A3-F393-E0A9-E50E24DCCA9E
and on nearby bluetooth devices list it shows C8:A7:63:72:75:3B

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried Apple's official [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonCentralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH3-SW1)?

Comment: Nothing is working: First, can you download LigthBlue.app on the AppStore and check if you can see you device? Also, you need to show some code, because we can't guess what's wrong. I'd say it's because of line 20 in one of your .m files.